# I want to keep checking the content of a label?

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I want to keep checking the content of a label, if label changes I need to fire an event.
I have an enum of Day, Week or Month, if one of those values comes in the label, i want to change my chart according the value in the label?

Comment: who is changing the label? your own code somewhere else in the same WPF executable?

Comment: I thinks its better to check the component which is driving the content of the label

Comment: is there no label_change event?

Comment: Users can't change labels, so you must be changing it in code, so just call your change function when you change it in the code behind.

Comment: yes i change it in code behind every time u press an arrow it changes.

Comment: @ThePower there is no change fucntion for a label in csharp ?

Comment: @Letoir I know, because it has no purpose. The user can't edit labels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following code to know when content changed

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ContentControl.ContentProperty, typeof(Label));
            if (dpd != null)
            {
                dpd.AddValueChanged(label1, delegate
                {
                    // Add property change logic.
                });
            }
```

At "// Add property change logic" you can check label's content ad fire event or do anything you want.

Comment: Do u think i can use this to check boolean values? or does boolean have this as an event?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind (two-way) the `Content` property of the label to property of an object which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Whenever there is any change in the property, you will have to raise `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: In all likelihood, since the OP wants notifications to the content of the label changing, it's already bound to some property. If not, the user would manually set the `Content`, overriding the binding. So this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: @Kshitij Mehta didn't get the point. If the content in the label changes, due to two way binding this will be reflected in the ViewModel instance. In the setter of that property code can be written which will do some changes with the property which is bound to the chart. I feel this is a cleaner(MVVM) way of doing things.